# jQuery add/ remove class when click on multiple div

Tags: jquery, class

I have 15 color choices for a card element, I don't want to create 15 lines of script for those color class. How should I change my code? and class "regcard cardlist" will be the basic style on it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#orange").click(function(){
    $("#card_color_choice").removeClass().addClass("regcard cardlist orange");
  });

  $("#green").click(function(){
    $("#card_color_choice").removeClass().addClass("regcard cardlist green");
  });

  $("#blue").click(function(){
    $("#card_color_choice").removeClass().addClass("regcard cardlist blue");
  });

});
```

```css
.regcard{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.orange{
  background-color: #FF6600;
  color: #EFEFEF;
}

.green{
  background-color: #47AC33;
  color: #EFEFEF;
}

.blue{
  background-color: #637eb6;
  color: #EFEFEF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Color Choices:<br/>
<a href="#" id="orange">Color1</a><br/>
<a href="#" id="green">Color2</a><br/>
<a href="#" id="blue">Color3</a>

<br/><br/>
<a href="#" target="_blank">
    <div id="card_color_choice" class="regcard cardlist orange" >
        Element inside
    </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a variable with the name of all class list and on click of button get the id of the clicked button append it to the variable and add the class to the div

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").click(function(){
  var a="regcard cardlist " + $(this).attr('id')
    $("#card_color_choice").removeClass().addClass(a);
  });

});
```

```css
.regcard{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.orange{
  background-color: #FF6600;
  color: #EFEFEF;
}

.green{
  background-color: #47AC33;
  color: #EFEFEF;
}

.blue{
  background-color: #637eb6;
  color: #EFEFEF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Color Choices:<br/>
<a href="#" id="orange">Color1</a><br/>
<a href="#" id="green">Color2</a><br/>
<a href="#" id="blue">Color3</a>

<br/><br/>
<a href="#" target="_blank">
    <div id="card_color_choice" class="regcard cardlist orange" >
        Element inside
    </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use click event on button and with the help of attributes solve your problem. E.g.

Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.color_btn').on('click', function() {
       let color = $(this).attr('color');
       $('#card_color_choice').removeClass().addClass("regcard cardlist "+color+"");
   });
});
```

html code:

```
Color Choices:<br/>
<a href="#" class="color_btn" id="orange" color="orange">Color1</a><br/>
<a href="#" class="color_btn" id="green" color="green">Color2</a><br/>
<a href="#" class="color_btn" id="blue" color="blue">Color3</a>

<br/><br/>
<a href="#" target="_blank">
<div id="card_color_choice" class="regcard cardlist orange" >
Element inside
</div>
```

Hope this little tricks helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Please Try this,

```js
   
   $('a').on('click', function() {
      var color=$(this).attr('color')
    // OR  var color = $(this).attr('id');
      $("#card_color_choice").removeClass().addClass("regcard cardlist "+color);
  });
```

```css
.regcard{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.orange{
  background-color: #FF6600;
  color: #EFEFEF;
}

.green{
  background-color: #47AC33;
  color: #EFEFEF;
}

.blue{
  background-color: #637eb6;
  color: #EFEFEF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Color Choices:<br/>
<a href="#" id="orange" color="orange" >Color1</a><br/>
<a href="#" id="green" color="green">Color2</a><br/>
<a href="#" id="blue" color="blue">Color3</a>

<br/><br/>
<a href="#" target="_blank">
    <div id="card_color_choice" class="regcard cardlist orange" >
        Element inside
    </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the jquery code a little bit , rest html and css are perfect.
Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.color_btn').on('click', function(){
     var color = $(this).attr('id');
     $('#card_color_choice').removeClass().addClass("regcard cardlist "+color+"");
   });
});
```

**NOTE:** Always try to store variables in data-attributes instead of self made custom attributes.

Hope this helps !! :)

Answer (score 0):

At first.Choose the same Classname  for all elements. then get the Id of the event

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".colorBtn").on('click',function() {
            $("#card_color_choice").removeClass();
            $("#card_color_choice").addClass('regcard cardlist ' + $(this).attr('id') );
        })
    });
```

```css
    .regcard{
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
    }

    .orange{
        background-color: #FF6600;
        color: #EFEFEF;
    }

    .green{
        background-color: #47AC33;
        color: #EFEFEF;
    }

    .blue{
        background-color: #637eb6;
        color: #EFEFEF;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Color Choices:<br/>
    <a href="#" class="colorBtn" id="orange">Color1</a><br/>
    <a href="#" class="colorBtn" id="green">Color2</a><br/>
    <a href="#" class="colorBtn" id="blue">Color3</a>

    <br/><br/>
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <div id="card_color_choice" class="regcard cardlist orange" >
            Element inside
        </div>
    </a>
```